# Backup oplog done but not complete

Tags: mongodb

I found the log show like this

```
2017-03-10T03:33:29.158+0000    [###################.....]  local.oplog.rs  4800969/6041391  (79.5%)
2017-03-10T03:33:31.023+0000    writing local.oplog.rs metadata to <dump_path>.......
2017-03-10T03:33:31.024+0000    done dumping local.oplog.rs (4809092 documents)
```

Does it backup completely or not? and Why is it show done if not finished?

Comment: Are you dumping the oplog from a replica set member which is still accepting writes? If so, it is expected that the count will not be accurate since older oplog documents may be removed to make room for newer ones (the oplog is a [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/)). If that isn't the case, can you provide more information such as the specific versions of `mongod`  and `mongodump` used, your `mongodump` command-line, the type of replica set member you are dumping from (primary or secondary), and any steps you've taken to stop writes to that member.

Comment: Hi Stennie, Yes, I'm dumping the oplog from secondary node that is still accepting writes from primary. What is the best practice to perform oplog dumping on Production environment? I saw some thread that suggests to remove secondary node from replica set and restart it without --replset parameter and do something when finish restart it back to replica set, but I concern sync time between primary and secondary that will take too long time. -- Hiko

Comment: What is your goal as far as dumping the oplog? If you want to backup a replica set member you should follow one of the supported [Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) in the documentation. For an active deployment (or one where data is much larger than RAM) the typical approach is using a backup agent (eg. MongoDB Cloud/Ops Manager) or filesystem snapshots.

Comment: My goal is copy oplog from production and replay on standby site because Production db is very huge if use mongodump it will take very very long time (more than 1 day) to process. My understanding, Ops manager is available for Enterprise edition but I'm using Community edition, cannot I use it?

Comment: If you are trying to use this as a backup approach, it will only be valid to replay the oplog on another deployment if the source and destination are consistent (i.e. destination is an earlier snapshot of the source deployment and both oplogs have an entry in common). MongoDB Ops/Cloud Manager could be used for a backup approach, but replication to a standby deployment is a different goal from creating backups. If you want to set up replication to a standby deployment, Mongo Connector would be a more suitable option: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks Stennie. It's useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replication oplog is a [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) so it is expected that the document count will not be accurate if you are running `mongodump` for the oplog on a replica set member that is actively accepting writes. Older oplog documents will automatically be removed to make room for newer ones, so counts will fluctuate.

If you want to set up replication to a standby deployment, [Mongo Connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki)  would be a more suitable option. Mongo Connector is an open source tool that can replicate from a MongoDB deployment to another MongoDB deployment or an external system such as Solr or Elasticsearch.

If you want to backup a replica set member you should follow one of the supported [Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) in the documentation. For an active deployment (or one where data is much larger than RAM) the typical approach is using a backup agent (eg. MongoDB Cloud/Ops Manager) or filesystem snapshots.

Note: replication and backup can both help with data recovery, but serve different purposes. For backup planning you should consider factors like recovery point objectives, recovery time objectives, and performance impact on your production deployment when taking backups.

For more information see:

- MongoDB white paper on [Backup and its Role in Disaster Recovery](http://s3.amazonaws.com/info-mongodb-com/MongoDB-backup-disaster-recovery.pdf)
- Mongo Connector: [Usage with Mong‌oDB](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-MongoDB).
- Cloud Manager's [Backup Preparations](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/core/backup-preparations/) documentation